# Whats wrong with this SQL Command? It should work

Tags: sql

Whats wrong with this sql code? Syntax should be ok or not?

```
public void setArtikelIdRegalfach(ArrayList <Integer> arikel_ID, int Regal_ID) { // Setzt die Regalfach ArtikelID
    try {
        String query = "UPDATE WARENLISTE SET ARTIKEL_ID Values (" + arikel_ID + ") WHERE Regal_ID = " + Regal_ID;
        st.executeUpdate(query);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you need is UPDATE WARENLISTE SET ARTIKEL_ID Values = " + arikel_ID + " WHERE Regal_ID = " + Regal_ID. I don't know that you can directly add an array, because each value must map to a column in the table.

Answer (score 3):

Update statements in SQL do not take a `VALUES` clause.  On top of this, you should be using a prepared statement.  Here is a corrected version:

```
String sql = "UPDATE WARENLISTE SET ARTIKEL_ID = ? WHERE Regal_ID = ?";
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("...");
     PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {

    ps.setInt(1, arikel_ID);
    ps.setInt(2, Regal_ID);

    ps.executeUpdate();
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot! But i want to add a ArrayList into my Database. Is this possible? Because i cant find a command which can looks like "ps.setArrayList(1, arikel_ID);"     I just find "ps.setArray" but this command dont even accept normale arrays like (int [] array)

Comment: If you want to use an array list as the source for the two ID parameters, then just use `get()` to access the correct elements.

Comment: You mistake what i want to do. I want to use an ArrayList to add more than 1 ArticleId into my Database (in one column). But is this even possible?

Comment: Then you might have to execute more than one update statement.

Comment: @Araggggoon Your understanding for setArray() method on preparedStatement may not be correct. It is not to support multiple records insert / update, rather it is to support insert / update of one column that is of any collections type. Some databases like Oracle support tables with VARRAY (& more) columns.